# how can I resize an image keeping its dimensions ratio when the file has just been uploaded by the user (as opposed to residing in the C drive)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image-processing

Few days ago, I posted a question on [how to resize an image while keeping the ratio of its dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233039/how-can-i-check-the-dimensions-of-a-image-so-that-i-can-reduce-them-proportionaly). I get an [nice answer](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4336) which helped me understand how to do so.

Unfortunately, I've not been yet capable of exploiting that to solve my problem. The main problem resides in the type of file used to process the image.

1° in the answer it's about creating an image file of type

```
System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:/path + filename");
```

2° In my case I'm getting an image uploaded by the user in my actionResult

```
public ActionResult UpLoadImage(HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
   //Now do something with image..
}
```

I've difficulty to create an Image object, first of all, because of the way the file System.Drawing.Image is created. **...FromFile(OriginalFile)** where OriginalFile is the **name + path** of the image **"C:/path/filename"**.

But the file I have has been uploaded and reside in a Database. And to access it, I make a query to the database.

To make the long story short, how can I resize an image keeping its dimensions ratio when the file has just been uploaded by the user (as opposed to residing in the C drive).

**EDIT**

How about if I want to save it (not to a c drive but) to a database? So far, what I do is to save (i) the image's data as byte and (ii) the Mime type as a string.

How do I save the Image of type ystem.Drawing.Image to database using the same Technicals?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [loading the image from stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx) (`Image.FromStream` method).

Comment: Image image = Image.FromStream(imageloaded). And I'm getting the following error: "Cannot concert 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase' to 'System.IO.Stream'"

Comment: That's normal, you should use the Stream of the uploaded file: `Image image = Image.FromStream(uploadedImage.InputStream)`

Comment: I've tried 'imageloaded.InputStream' instead of just 'imageloaded', and it didn't produce any error. That's the first step. I'll try to work and see how everything works.

Comment: Your current technique of storing the image byte array representation and the MIME type in the database is exactly how it should be done. `System.Drawing.Image` is a .NET type and a relational database knows nothing about it.

Comment: For how to convert the image object to the DB I've found out a post on CodeProjet so that I was able to solve the second part. See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ImageConverter.aspx