# C#: Why reduction of the size of an images leads to very bad quality of those images? Anything I can do

Tags: c#, image-processing

Few days ago, I asked a question about [how to reduce the size of an image while keeping its ratio's dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233039/how-can-i-check-the-dimensions-of-a-image-so-that-i-can-reduce-them-proportionaly). I was finally able to get it work. Now when the user uploads an image, 3 copies of it (with different dimensions) are saved to the database.

But, unfortunately, that dimensions' reduction degrades sensibly the quality of images uploaded. Only the copy that has been saved without dimensions has kept its quality.

Am I supposed to expect those reduction of quality? the image look really bad (like a news paper's photo).

Is there anything I can do? mighty an option I need to set up in my code.

Thanks for helping

Comment: If these are JPEGs, you may want to change your compression settings - JPEGs are lossy, and they achieve smaller sizes by sacrificing quality. What are you using for the resizing? There should be some parameter either in the resize method, or in the save method, which allows you to set the compression level.

Comment: The code is pretty much the one that's in the article I mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because the [Image.GetThumbnailImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx) function that you are using is only intended to make low quality images.

See these remarks from the MSDN documentation on GetThumbnailImage:

> The GetThumbnailImage method works
>   well when the requested thumbnail
>   image has a size of about 120 x 120
>   pixels. If you request a large
>   thumbnail image (for example, 300 x
>   300) from an Image that has an
>   embedded thumbnail, there could be a
>   noticeable loss of quality in the
>   thumbnail image. It might be better to
>   scale the main image (instead of
>   scaling the embedded thumbnail) by
>   calling the DrawImage method.

For a good example of how to perform high quality image scaling in C# see this question:

[High Quality Image Scaling C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/high-quality-image-scaling-c/353222#353222)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure how the code you linked to works.

Here's a better example.

[Resizing a Photographic image with GDI+ for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageresize.aspx)

The essence of it:

```
Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight, 
                            PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, 
                      imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto, 
                  new Rectangle(destX,destY,destWidth,destHeight),
                  new Rectangle(sourceX,sourceY,sourceWidth,sourceHeight),
                  GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Look at the settings like `InterpolationMode` which allows you to control the quality (processing speed vs. quality).